# How to Navigate in React Native Paper Bottom Navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-native-paper

How do I navigate from a screen in react native paper bottom navigation, in this example I should be able to navigate to albums screen from music screen, but navigation is undefined in the screen.

snack link: https://snack.expo.dev/@nitzme/bottom-navigation-example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';

const CenterView = ({children}) => {  return (
<View style={{ height: '100%', flexDirection: 'column',
 justifyContent: 'center', 
 alignItems: 'center' }}>{children}</View>
)}

const MusicRoute = ({navigation, route}) => {

console.log(navigation, route);
const swichToAlbum = () => {
  navigation.navigate('albums');
}
return (
  <CenterView>
    <Text>Music</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={{swichToAlbum}}>
      <Text>Go to Album screen</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </CenterView>
)
}

const AlbumsRoute = () => <CenterView><Text>Albums</Text></CenterView>;

const RecentsRoute = () => <CenterView><Text>Recents</Text></CenterView>;

const NotificationsRoute = () => <CenterView><Text>Notifications</Text></CenterView>;

const App = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'music', title: 'Music', focusedIcon: 'heart', unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline'},
    { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', focusedIcon: 'album' },
    { key: 'recents', title: 'Recents', focusedIcon: 'history' },
    { key: 'notifications', title: 'Notifications', focusedIcon: 'bell', unfocusedIcon: 'bell-outline' },
  ]);

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    music: MusicRoute,
    albums: AlbumsRoute,
    recents: RecentsRoute,
    notifications: NotificationsRoute,
  });

  return (
    <BottomNavigation
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      shifting={false}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> to naviagate on click you have to create a stack navigator.

**Hope the below link will help you to figure out your solution**

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-bottom-navigation/

Comment: no i am not looking for stack navigator, i have used react navigation material bottom tab navigator and when passing the screen name correctly to navigation.navigate we can navigate to the next tab from the current screen. i want this same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems 1 way to achieve this is by making the `[index, setIndex]` global by using context and then updating the `index` from any other component can be used to navigate between screens.

same way the `routes array` is passed to the route, so if you need to pass data via route you can update the routes array by making it as a global context.
then update the index.

Haven't found a better solution yet.

example: https://snack.expo.dev/@nitzme/bottom-navigation-example